# Angular 8.1 - Website Searching Lazy Loading Module .js File in Root Folder

Tags: angular

I'm new at Angular Lazy Loading. When i run the website it searches the lazy loading module .js file in Root folder (not in js folder). Then it gives missing js file error. I'm waiting for your answers. Thanks.

Edit :

I'm using Asp.Net MVC and i'm using Local IIS (localhost/RentACar). My app.module.ts file has this line : providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/RentACar/' } Also my mvc layout page has this line :  All other pages work fine except lazy loading page. –

It searches lazy loading file in root folder then it gives an error like that : 'missing js file - localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js' it should be like that : 'localhost/RentACar/Content/js/libs/views-about-about-module.js'

Edit 2 :

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk views-about-about-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js)
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk views-about-about-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js)

Edit 3 :

[image]

app.routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, PreloadAllModules } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './views/shared/layout';
import { IndexComponent } from './views/home/index';
const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
        { path: '', component: IndexComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
        { path: 'Index', component: IndexComponent },
        { path: 'About', loadChildren: () => import('./views/about/about.module').then(m => m.AboutModule), data: { preload: true } }
    ]
},

{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: false, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload', preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppComponent } from './app';
import { LayoutComponent } from './views/shared/layout';
import { HeaderComponent } from './views/shared/controls/header';
import { FooterComponent } from './views/shared/controls/footer';
import { ScriptsComponent } from './views/shared/controls/scripts';
import { SharedBookNowComponent } from './views/shared/common/booknow';
import { SharedCallUsComponent } from './views/shared/common/callus';
import { SharedModalAlertComponent } from './views/shared/common/modalalert';
import { SharedModalConfirmComponent } from './views/shared/common/modalconfirm';
import { IndexComponent } from './views/home';
import { SiteService } from './services/site';
import { Lib } from './lib/methods';
@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AppComponent,

    //Layout
    LayoutComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    ScriptsComponent,

    //Shared
    SharedBookNowComponent,
    SharedCallUsComponent,
    SharedModalAlertComponent,
    SharedModalConfirmComponent,

    //Home
    IndexComponent,
],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule.withConfig({ warnOnNgModelWithFormControl: 'never' }),
    HttpClientModule
],

providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/RentACar/' },
    SiteService,
    Lib,
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

about.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AboutComponent } from '../../views/about';
import { AboutHeaderComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/header';
import { AboutBreadCumbsComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/breadcumbs';
import { AboutBestComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/best';
import { AboutWhatComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/what';
import { AboutMoreComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/more';
import { AboutWorkersComponent } from '../../views/about/parts/workers';

import { AboutRoutingModule } from './about-routing.module';
import { SiteService } from '../../services/site';
import { Lib } from '../../lib/methods';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


@NgModule({
declarations: [
    AboutComponent,
    AboutHeaderComponent,
    AboutBreadCumbsComponent,
    AboutBestComponent,
    AboutWhatComponent,
    AboutMoreComponent,
    AboutWorkersComponent,
],
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AboutRoutingModule
],

providers: [
    SiteService,
    Lib,
]
})
export class AboutModule { }
```

about.routing.module.ts :

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AboutComponent } from '.';

const routes: Routes = [
        { path: 'About', component: AboutComponent },
];

@NgModule({
imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AboutRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
Open index.html and look for `<base href="/" />` Edit it to match the correct folder

Option 2:
build the project and redeploy with the correct `--base-href` parameter

example:

```
ng build --prod --base-href /<domain>
```

read more here https://angular.io/guide/deployment

EDIT 1

Do you have custom paths for lazy modules in angular.json ?

```
{
  "projects": {
    "your-app-name": {
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "lazyModules": [
              "src/app/example-module/example.module"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this is for custom lazy load modules. Lazy router modules will be discovered automatically

Comment: I'm using Asp.Net MVC and i'm using Local IIS (localhost/RentACar). My app.module.ts file has this line : providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/RentACar/' } Also my mvc layout page has this line : <base href="/RentACar/" /> All other pages work fine except lazy loading page.

Comment: It searches lazy loading file in root folder then it gives an error like that : 'missing js file - localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js' it should be like that : 'localhost/RentACar/Content/js/libs/views-about-about-module.js'

Comment: I don't have any custom paths. Do i need to add those lines?

Comment: I added those lines but still it searched module js file in Root folder.

Comment: This is the error : "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk views-about-about-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js)
ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk views-about-about-module failed.
(missing: http://localhost/RentACar/views-about-about-module.js)"

Comment: Are you talking about build time or runtime? Can you show please the code where you load your modules

Comment: I added the codes to main message.